# How to solve the problem with design adaptability

Tags: html, css

What is the problem. For adaptability, I decided to use the GRID system, however, I have an annoying object - the user's nickname (profile-subnick), the problem is that when using a fixed column size (for example, 200 pixels, and for example 8 columns), the columns, respectively - static and do not move anywhere, however, when using, for example, 33 percent of the size of the columns, they, accordingly, are reduced to the size of the window, this is good, but the problem is that the user’s nickname moves along with the columns (well, this is logical, actually), like I can make sure that the column remains changeable, and the user's nickname moves along the trajectory of the path I need, since at the moment it simply creeps under the profile avatar and such a result is not suitable for me, for example, it would be good if it turned out to be then under the profile or something else. If you change some individual parts of the code, achievements will be affected, which in all cases should be static and under the avatar, or the avatar itself will disappear somewhere. To be honest, I more or less understand what is happening inside the GRID code, but I am already very confused.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
display: grid;
}

.achievements { /* Major changes to the achievement table. */
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 15;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  justify-items: left;
  position: relative; 
}

.achi:hover::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: help;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ach, .ach1 { /* Positioning icons within the achievement table */
   margin: 500px;
   padding: 10px;
}

.achievement-table { /* Achievements table. */
  width: 32%;
  grid-column: 1;
  border: none;
  grid-row: 15;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 2px solid aqua;
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  background-color: #190b14
}

.achievement-table td { /* Positioning table cells */
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Profile { /* Header part of the page, Banner, avatar, nickname, other nickname and achievements*/
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 200px); /* 8 non-adaptive columns, 200 pixels each, when changed to adaptive units - shifted Profile-subnick */
 background-color: #190b14;
 grid-template-rows:  repeat(18, 50px); /* 18 lines non-adaptive of 50 pixels each, when changing to adaptive units of measurement, achivments jumps */
}

.Profile-pfp { /* User avatar*/
  display: grid; 
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 10;
  margin-left: 1vw;
  top: 550px;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  z-index: 1; 
}

.Profile-pfp img { /* Fixed avatar size */
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
}

.profile-subnick { /* The problematic element is the user's main nickname */
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 12;
  background-color: transparent;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Profile.css" />
  <title>Your Profile</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <aside class="Sidebar-container">
       <nav class="Sidebar">
        <div class="logo"><span class="tf-logo">Tattoo Foundler</span></div>
        <button class="sidebar-button">
          <img class="sideicon" src="css/home1.png" alt="Home">
          <span>
          Home
          </span>
        </button>
        <button class="sidebar-button">
          <img class="sideicon" src="css/search2.png" alt="Search">
          <span>
          Search
          </span>
        </button>
        <button class="sidebar-button">
          <img class="sideicon" src="css/envelope3.png" alt="Messages">
          <span>
          Messages
          </span>
        </button>
        <button class="sidebar-button">
          <img class="sideicon" src="css/heart1.png" alt="Favorites">
          <span>
          Favorites
          </span>
        </button>
       </nav>
    </aside>
    
    <section class="Profile">
      <div class="secondary-nick">
        <div>
          <h3>CharonIkh</h3>
          <img src="css/banner1.jfif" id="banner">
          <span>50 Sketches</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Profile-pfp">
         <img src="css/180x180.png" alt="pfp" > 
      </div>
      <div class="profile-subnick">
        <h3>CharonIkh</h3>
        <span>@CharonIkh</span>
      </div>
      <figure class="achievements">
        <div class="row">
          <table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" class="achievement-table" title="соси">
            <tr>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/medalred.png"></td>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/medalgreen.png"></td>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/medalblue.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/badgered.png"></td>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/badgegreen.png"></td>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/badgeblue.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/medalorange.png"></td>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/medallime.png"></td>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/medalmarine.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/badgeorange.png"></td>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/badgelime.png"></td>
              <td><img class="achi" src="css/badgemarine.png"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </section>
    

  </body>
</html>
```

This is roughly what it all looks like now.

[full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdL7Z.jpg)

[adaptive small size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puQ9C.png)

[non-adaptive small size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TEsG.png)

I won’t say anything about the banner, it’s not so important now, when it’s reduced, it should disappear completely.
By the way, initially the Banner and the top nickname were separate sections, but I decided to combine them into one, since in the previous version there were problems with the columns and lines of the grid system, but now there are no such problems, and the avatar did not want to climb onto the banner in any way )